# NUnit appSettings file attribute (linked config file) is not seen by ConfigurationManager in test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have NUnit test (version 2.6.4) test. It uses `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"]` to retrive a configuration setting from the `app.config` file (which is in the test project). This is my `App.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="bar.config">
    <add key="thisSettingIsVisible" value="yes, indeed"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and this is bar.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="foo" value="this setting isn't visible"/>
</appSettings>
```

I'm using ReSharper 10 test runner to execute the test. `bar.config` file is copied to the `bin/Debug` directory. In fact, that configuration was working some time ago, but stopped. Any clues what can be wrong?

Now, I've figured out a workaround, but I'm not happy with this solution:

```
private static void InitializeAppSettings()
{
    var exeAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var assemblyName = exeAssembly.GetName().Name + ".dll";
    var testDllFolder = new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exeAssembly.CodeBase)).LocalPath;
    var openExeConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Path.Combine(testDllFolder, assemblyName));
    foreach (var setting in openExeConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
    {
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[setting] = openExeConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings[setting].Value;
    }
}
```

BTW. I can't abstract away `ConfigurationManager` usage form existing, legacy code.

Comment: What exact ReSharper 10 build do you use? We fixed similar issue about copying config file in R# 10.0.2 build https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450410.

Comment: I've been using ReSharper 10.0.0, after upgrading to R# 10.0.2 problem disappeared. Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use R# 10.0.0 or R# 10.0.1 - it is [a known issue for such builds](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450410) and it has been fixed in R# 10.0.2 build.

Answer (score 2):

I replicated your use case and found that my additional config worked in the context of an ASP.NET site but the additional appSetting was null in a test project until I changed the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy Always`

[image]

Comment: No, that's not the case. I've wrote explicitly: "bar.config file is copied to the bin/Debug directory".

Comment: Note that this answer is likely correct if you have the latest version of ReSharper installed.